# DateTime.AddDays what value to pass to generate an exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a small utility class that generate a hash code with input data. What class does & its algorithm is not significant to the question but it looks like below:

```
public static class HashCodeHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return a hash code to be added to the link in download data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="baseDateTime">Today's date</param>
    /// <param name="rrid">Profile ID</param>
    /// <param name="downloadCode">Download code to be used for hash code generation.</param>
    /// <returns>Final result is a string in this format "20140715385"</returns>
    public static string GenerateHashCodeForExportLink(DateTime baseDateTime, int rrid, string downloadCode)
    {
        var todayDate = baseDateTime;

        int expireInDays;

        if (!int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExportLinkExpireInDays"], out expireInDays))
            expireInDays = 30; // If not specified in web.config file then use default value

        var expiryDate = todayDate.AddDays(expireInDays);

        var currentDay = todayDate.Day;

        var expiryMonth = expiryDate.Month;

        char nthChar = Convert.ToChar(downloadCode.Substring(expiryMonth - 1, 1));
        var asciiValue = (int)nthChar;
        var mod = (rrid % currentDay);

        var computedHash = (asciiValue * expiryMonth) + currentDay + mod;

        var fullHashCode = todayDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + computedHash;

        return fullHashCode;
    }
}
```

I was writing unit test cases for this class and realized that `AddDays()` can throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, below line:

```
var expiryDate = todayDate.AddDays(expireInDays);
```

So I should write a test and i did write below test case:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GenerateHashCodeForExportLink_IncorrectDate_Throw()
    {
        try
        {
            HashCodeHelper.GenerateHashCodeForExportLink(new DateTime(2015, 1, 31), 501073, "001-345-673042");
            Assert.Fail("Exception is not thrown");
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Incorrect exception thrown");
        }
    }
```

The problem is, i do not know what to pass to cause `AddDays()` method to throw exception? I tried passing random dates e.g. 1-1-1800, 30-Jan-2015, etc.

I looked at `AddDays()` method implementation but could not make out. Any idea?

Comment: [DateTime.AddDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown when *the resulting DateTime is less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue.*

Comment: You can also use the attribute `[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]` on the method instead of catching the exception yourself.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I often use ExpectedException approach, however, here as now shown in my code, i am using try catch approach. I intend to pass only in case ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown.

Comment: That is exactly what that attribute does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in `int.MaxValue`, that should end up with a value which is outside the representable range for `DateTime`, whatever the original `DateTime` is.

Sample code, tested on [csharppad.com](http://csharppad.com):

```
DateTime.MinValue.AddDays(int.MaxValue);
```

Using `Assert.Fail` in a `finally` block is a mistake though... that will *always* be called. It's not clear what your test framework is, but I'd expect something like:

```
Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => /* code here */);
```

Comment: You are right, I wrote finally while writing this question. As soon as i tested, i realized it should not be there. Thanks.

Comment: @SBirthare: You should still use `Assert.Throws` or the equivalent in your unit testing framework - much cleaner :)

Comment: I often use ExpectedException approach, however, here as now shown in my code, i am using try catch approach. I intend to pass only in case ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown. what do you think?

Comment: @SBirthare: If you mean the `ExpectedException` attribute, that's not a good idea - it means that if the exception is thrown *anywhere* in the method, it will pass. You want to limit the scope of where the exception can be thrown. `Assert.Throws` describes exactly what you want, in a very precise way. I thoroughly recommend it.

Comment: Thank you so much Jon. You gave me one more reason to stop using ExpectedException attribute. If you allow me, I just wanted to confirm, I defined two catch block, one which will cause my test to pass. Another to fail the test as something other than expected has happened. Is using Exception class in this case break the design rule?

Answer (score 0):

use double.MaxValue as your parameter in the AddDays method.

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
time.AddDays(double.MaxValue);
```

ArgumentOutOfRangeException is triggered when you go beyond the capability of the DateTime class.

Answer (score 0):

Another method can be:

```
DateTime.MaxValue.AddDays(1);
```

or

```
DateTime.MinValue.AddDays(DateTime.MaxValue.Day +1);
```

Those codes should be throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException